# Why does the data point appear in my pivot table if the table it is referencing doesn't contain the same data point?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

The pivot table contains the data point:

[image: Data Point]

The pivot table is referencing this table:

[image: Table]

As you can see, the data point is not in the table. This table is connected to a query. I am guessing the reason the pivot table contains the data point still is because the query still contains the data point. Is this correct?

I've tried refreshing the pivot table to get rid of the data point, but it still remains in the pivot table after the refresh.